# Child associated nodes not coming

Tags: 7

OK, so here's my problem

I am using [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/shs) module.

I have a taxonomy structure like this

Parent
-Child 1
-Child 2

... And I have contents linked to these terms like this
Content 1 - Parent
Content 2 - Child 1
Content 3 - Child 2
Content 4 - Child 2

So apparently if I select the Parent term in an exposed filter its only showing Content 1 and not all the 4 contents. Is it normal with this module? Isnt there a workaround for this?

Help appreciated...

Comment: Further to this, I think its more a tweak to be done with the exposed filter rather than the Simple Hierarchical Select module

Comment: http://webwash.net/tutorials/using-simple-hierarchical-select-module-drupal-7

scroll down to see view integration
it says " select the "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; Simple hierarchical select)" filter." did you try that?

Comment: Yeah, the break up of multiple dropdowns based on parent-child relationship is coming fine, thanks to this module. But, as I said, even if i dont use this module, and select the "Has taxonomy term" or "Has taxonomy terms (with depth)" the result is the same. That is if I select a parent category in the exposed filter, I am not getting all the nodes/contents that are associated with the parent and all of its children.

Comment: So foolish of me.. just needed to set the depth to 1 while building the exposed filter :P

Apologies...